# Понятие приватизации

Tags: лексика, терминология

Армянская государственная инспекция по языку объясняя понятие **"приватизация"** утверждает, что, **когда человек приватизирует свою квартиру, он передает ее кому-нибудь другому, делает ее собственностью последнего.** *Т.е. приватизировать квартиру не означает стать ее собственником.*

У Кузнецова: П. квартиру **(выкупить у государства).** Т.е., если верить Кузнецову, получается как раз наоборот:  **тот, кто приватизирует квартиру, например, становится ее собственником.**

Вопрос: что понимать под термином "Приватизация"? В Википедии написано, но очень сумбурно, ответа на вопрос я не нашел.

Comment: Пожалуй, не стоит верить тому, что **армянская** государственная инспекция говорит о **русском** языке.

Comment: Из Википедии: `Приватизация — форма преобразования собственности, представляющая собой процесс передачи-продажи (полной или частичной) государственной (муниципальной) собственности в частные руки. ` Что именно в этом предложении сумбурно, что в нём вы не смогли понять?

Comment: Nick Volynkin, что армянская государственная инспекция говорит об армянском языке. Это просто решил уточнить, что значит "приватизировать в русском языке".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общепринятым пониманием термина "приватизация" является передача собственности государства к частным собственникам, для сравнения: "национализация" - передача собственности от частных собственников к государству.

Синонимы:

- приватизация = разгосударствление имущества
- национализация =  осударствление имущества

Соответственно, если государственный служащий употребляет слово "приватизация", то это означает, что государство отдаёт долю в принадлежащих государству предприятиях частным лицам.

А если слово "приватизация" употребляется частным лицом, то это означает, что частное лицо приобретает долю в принадлежащем государству имуществу.

Передача собственности может быть полной, неполной, с компенсацией, без компенсации -- это уже детали.

Обсуждать толкование этого понятия армянской государственной инспекцией я не буду. Как минимум -- приводите точные цитаты.

Comment: Проблема в том, что, когда возникло понятие "приватизировать" в армянском языке это слово начали путать, употреблять вместо "присвоить", сделать собственностью". Поэтому вмешалось армянская государственная инспекция.

Comment: Цитирую: Приватизирует государство,  и в результате государственная собственность становится частной собственностью, а жители квартиры становятся собственниками. Коротко говоря, жители присваивают, делают собственностью. ***Но, если , однако, частное лицо приватизирует свою квартиру, он передает ее, дарит ее другому лицу, делая ее собственностью последнего***.

Comment: @Серж Мне очень не хочется комментировать цитату: у меня большие подозрения, что автор цитаты некометентен и плохо понимает имущественные отношения, путает различные понятия ("дарить" собственность - это совершенно иное действие, чем "завещание", "аренда" или "приватизация"). Но это совершенно не тематика сообщества по русскому языку -- вам к юристам с этим вопросом. Пусть они подымают документы на армянском (русский не является официальным языком в Армении), точно трактуют термины, основываясь на законодательстве Армении.

Comment: Я знаю, что не является. Мне нужно знать, чтобы правильно переводить тексты.  Армянском инспекция все верно трактует. Я просто хотел знать, как правильно в русском.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно Толковому словарю русского языка С. И. Ожегова (28-е издание), *приватизация - передача государственного или муниципального имущества за плату или безвозмездно в частную собственность*. Словари Н. Ю. Шведовой, С. А. Кузнецова, Современный экономический словарь и Словарь языка конца XX века дают схожие определения.

Таким образом, приватизация - это передача **либо государственного, либо муниципального имущества** в частную собственность.

Comment: Это понятно. А что значит "приватизировать"?

Comment: @Серж Приватизировать - передать (передавать) государственное или муниципальное имущество за плату или безвозмездно в частную собственность. *П. магазин, п. завод, п. печатный орган.*

Comment: Т.е. , если я скажу, что я приватизировал квартиру значит я ее выкупил у государства или я ***подарил ее другому, сделалл ее его собственностью?*** Весь мой вопрос к этому и сходиться.

Comment: @Серж Если вы говорите, что вы приватизировали квартиру -- это означает, что раньше квартира принадлежала государству, а вы её выкупили и стали собственником. Далее, как собственник помещения, вы вправе как угодно распоряжаться своей собственностью: дарить, завещать и т.п. Можно квартиру приватизировать сразу на несколько собственников: жила семья, после приватизации долевыми собственниками стали все члены семьи. Конструкция "я приватизировал квартиру на свою жену" -- это нонсенс. Жена может свою квартиру приватизировать (на себя), вы свою (на себя).